# Should I use Delegation or DataStore to passing data BACKWARD in Clean Swift architecture?

Tags: swift, architecture, clean-architecture

Now i'm trying to learn about Clean Swift architecture.

I'm using `DataStore` to passing data to next `viewController` and calling backward-`viewController's interactor` to do something when I want to send data backward like `delegation`.

I don't sure that this is suit with architecture. **Please show me how.**

I know that it is good to use `DataStore` for passing data **FORWARD** to next `viewController`. But is it good to use `DataStore` for passing data **BACKWARD**?

As all of my `tableViewCells`, `collectionViewCells`, etc. using `delegation` to sending any actions or datas to it's `viewController`, Will it be good and less confusing to use `delegation` for sending data **BACKWARD** too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Delegation is the preferred way to do it in iOS, because it allows you to keep code components decoupled. The current view controller should not be really concerned who is its delegate, whether it's another view controller or some coordinator.

To recap:

- For passing data forward, use Dependency Injection
- To pass data backwards, use Delegation

For passing data backwards, we can also use Closure Properties, but personally I am not a big fan of doing it this way.